# Pop up window code fails

Tags: javascript, html, popup, popupwindow

I am trying to open a pop-up window by clicking a button inside a form. MY code is as follows

HTML

```
<form>
    <div class="form" align="center">
         <button class="form_sub_btn" onclick="popitup()">Next</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
function popitup(url) {
    newwindow=window.open(url,"","height=400,width=350");  
    if(!newindow){
        alert('We have detected that you are using popup blocking software.');}
    if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus();}
}
function popitup(){
    window.open("","","height=300, width=300");
}
```

The latter function I put cause the former one wasn't getting executed with the url given.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the second `popitup` function. You need only the first one. Pass the URL to open in the argument. E.g., `popitup('/popup.html');`.

Since this button is inside a form, the button will cause the form to be submitted, which will navigate away from the current page before the popup can be opened. To prevent this, you need to `return false` from the onclick handler:

```
<button class="form_sub_btn" onclick="popitup('/popup.html'); return false;">Next</button>
```

Also, to make this work, it will be necessary to fix the typo in `popitup`: `if(!newindow){` should be `if(!newwindow){`, because any error in that function will prevent the `return false;` from executing.

Comment: I have already tried that. Tried it again. Still no pop up opens up.

Comment: It works now, forgot to add the closing tag. Thanks!!